# Laravel RBAC different behaviours

Tags: laravel, eloquent, rbac

I am using this [package](https://github.com/DynamicCodeNinja/RBAC) for laravel 5.2, and I get different behaviour when using sending different results from controller to view:

When I do a query like this:

```
$users = User::all();
```

Then in my view I can check for user roles like this:

```
@if($user->is('admin'))
```

Which is expected behaviour, but when I send a result from query like this:

```
$users = User::leftjoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
               ->orderBy(DB::raw('role_id IS NULL'))
               ->groupBy('users.id')
               ->orderBy('role_id')
               ->get();
```

I can't do a check like I am supposed to, but I need to check it like this:

```
@if($user->role_id ==1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to add select the main table when you're querying joins:

```
$users = User::leftjoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
           ->select('users.*')
           ->orderBy(DB::raw('role_id IS NULL'))
           ->groupBy('users.id')
           ->orderBy('role_id')
           ->get();
```

then in your view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($user->is('admin'))
         (...)
    @endif
@endforeach
```

If this won't help then you'll have to check what type is `item`. Probably  some other bundle disrupt querying the models and returning a `stdClass` instead of `User` model.

Comment: Didn't know that would make a difference, thank you, that solved it!